# ASP.NET MVC EF 6 + AJAX, after EF update there is ~8s wait time at clr.dll (delay Ajax => JsonResult action)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, performance, entity-framework

So I have an issue with the ASP.NET MVC performance.

Basically everything is working fast until I will add/update a record anywhere in web app (it is a bigger app so there is no point to include code).

I am using

```
public class AspNetContext : DbContext
{
    public AspNetContext() : base("DefaultConnection") {
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; }

    public class AspNetSqlContext : AspNetContext
    {
        public DbSet<Model.AspNetModels.AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
    }

}
```

for DAL class.

Then Repo class:

```
 public class AspNetUsersRepository
{
    private string MemberId;

    public AspNetUsersRepository(string memberId)
    {
        MemberId = memberId;
    }


    // CRUD

    public void UpdateUser(Model.AspNetModels.AspNetUsers aspNetUser)
    {
        using (AspNetContext.AspNetSqlContext context = new AspNetContext.AspNetSqlContext())
        {
            context.Entry(aspNetUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }




    //Single
    public Model.AspNetModels.AspNetUsers AspNetUsersByMemberId()
    {
        using (AspNetContext.AspNetSqlContext context = new AspNetContext.AspNetSqlContext())
        {
            return context.AspNetUsers.Single(m => m.Id == MemberId);

        }


    }





    //Checks
    public bool CheckIfEmailFree(string email)
    {


        using (AspNetContext.AspNetSqlContext context = new AspNetContext.AspNetSqlContext())
        {
            if (context.AspNetUsers.Any(m => m.Email == email))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }

    public bool CheckIfUsernameFree(string username)
    {
        using (AspNetContext.AspNetSqlContext context = new AspNetContext.AspNetSqlContext())
        {
            if (context.AspNetUsers.Any(m => m.UserName == username))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Then in a controller I am declaring it as

```
private DAL.AspNet.AspNetUsersRepository AspNetUsersRepo;

public ExampleController(){
AspNetUsersRepo = new AspNetUsersRepository("null");
}
```

That is a basically a pattern that I am using for all tables/models.

For last couple months everything was working just fine, unfortunately lately I start adding a new feature that shows data as charts / tables at one page.

I am using AJAX calls to JsonResult actions. Everything is very fast

[Performance pre-EF update/save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m8Ac.png)

Unfortunately after I update/save ANYTHING in DB I will get this performance:

[After EF upodate/save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTKKF.png)

Doesn't matter what is updated, it could a simply object that has just 2 records in table (2 columns, int & bool). As soon as EF hits it, the performance goes to drain.

I have tried to check what is causing it using dotTrace, it also shows a huge performance hit ( 947ms vs 8168ms after saving/updating to database).

7932ms from 8168ms is spent in clr.dll and therefore cannot say what is happening.

During debugging I have checked how much time it takes between actual call of the JsonResult action and the return of data and it takes ~ 5ms - 300ms.

Unfortunately it looks like something is causing a huge delay between AJAX => ??? => JsonResult action, as actions seems to be executed at the same speed.

Plus dotTrace also shows that most of the time is lost in clr.dll...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK !!! I HAVE FOUND THE SOLUTION !!!

IT IS NOT ENTITY FRAMEWORK !

It turned out that it was MVC fault. MVC has some kind of limit for concurrent connection that may request R/W access.

I am not sure why it was blocking AJAX AFTER I update/insert to DB, but it did.

Solution to this is to add (actually I have found John Culviner [post with explanation](http://johnculviner.com/asp-net-concurrent-ajax-requests-and-session-state-blocking/) by a mistake:

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)] attribute for a controller. (it could be also Disabled instead ReadOnly).
```

After this, AJAX requests are not blocked and all can concur at the same time.

Now everything went back to normal.

Still have to investigate and perhaps move whole project to Dapper (I like the Contrib addon which makes it fairly close to EF functionality, yet offering much smaller overhead, in my case the difference is not huge between EF / Dapper, but already noticeable ~ 30% faster + I have full control over SQL statement).

Thanks for your help.